# Retrieve printer URI in Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, uri

I have a Python script to detect whether a USB printer is plugged in, which at first finds the URI of the printer (given its name). In OSX I've managed to get this working using pycups (using getPrinterAttributes), but I'm having trouble repeating this with Windows.

I am attempting to use the win32print.GetPrinter method, but this doesn't give any of the details I'm looking for.

Here is the relevant code for Mac:

```
import cups

conn = cups.Connection()
attr = conn.getPrinterAttributes(name)
uri = attr['device-uri']
```

So far this is all I've got for Windows. I was hoping to be able to get the URI from details, but there is no such attribute.

```
import win32print

openP = win32print.OpenPrinter("zebra")
details = win32print.GetPrinter(openP,2)
```

I am very inexperienced with this sort of thing, and so far Google hasn't helped me. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: Sorry, have added now.

Comment: Have you tried using other info levels, such as `details = win32print.GetPrinter(openP,9)`?

Comment: I've tried changing varying this value from 0 to 9 and had no luck. Level 2 gave me the most info, but none gave URI.

Comment: I do not think it's possible with the `win32print` module. You can, however, try out [pycups](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycups).